# How to access individual buttons in a partial user class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Forgive my stupidity in asking this question. I am retired and have not looked at SQL or visual studio in over 20 years. Believe me, 20 years ago it was quite different. I got bored and decided to learn SQL, VS, VB .net and C#.

I have created a partial user class that I use on different forms. The class has nine buttons, one of which is an exit. When I exit the form, I want to return to the calling form.

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to address the click event of the individual buttons in the class I have created once the class has been added to a form.

All of the buttons are declared as public. There seems to be no events to handle the 'click' of a button??? Or anyway to identify which button was clicked???

Thanks,

Mike

**Form with partial class**

[image: Form with partial class.]

Figured I could capture the button that was clicked here, but everything I've tried bombed.

```
Private Sub UserControl11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.Click
    'How to identify which button has been clicked
    Dim oButton As DirectCast(sender, Text)
    MsgBox(oButton.text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is for the user control to raise a dedicated event. Internally, the user control handles the `Click` event of the `Button`. It then raises its own event that the form handles. The form doesn't care about the `Click` event of the user control. It cares about this event dedicated to the click of that specific `Button`:

```vb
Public Event ExitButtonClick As EventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub OnExitButtonClick(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ExitButtonClick(Me, e)
End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    OnExitButtonClick(EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

The form now handles `ExitButtonClick` like it would any other event. You can name the event something else if you like.

For more information on defining your own events, see my blog post [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: Thx for your help.

Comment: @MGC, if this answer solved your issue, please accept it. Apart from anything else, that lets everyone know that you need no more help without their having to open the question and read the whole thing.

Comment: Thx. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Thx. Problem solved. I'm sure this works however, I figured out a workaround and created a panel containing the buttons.

Solution there was simple - hope this makes more sense:

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    'Exit Form
    Call LogOut()

    Me.Hide()
    Me.Close()
    MainScreen.Show()

    'Get line of login for user
    con.Open()

    Dim dteOut As String = Format(DateTime.Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm tt")

    sqlAction = "Update LogonTable set DateOut = '" & dteOut & "'" & " Where UserName = '" & strUserName & "' and DateIn =  '" & LoginDate & "'"
    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlAction, con)
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What the hell?! I don't see how this bears any relation to the question you asked. In fact, I'm quite sure it doesn't. It seems like a solution to a problem that you didn't actually ask a question about.

Comment: I think what you're saying is that you did something other than what you describe in your question and so the question is now moot. In that case, you should delete the question, not post an answer that doesn't answer the question you asked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).